# Lua adding/changing global variables from C

Tags: c, variables, lua

I have a small Lua script:

```
function g ()
    print( AUp);
end
```

From C I load the script, add a variable with Name AUp and let it run a few hundred times.

```
for( i=0; i<2000; i++)
{
    num= i;
    lua_pushnumber( L, i);
    lua_setglobal( L, "AUp");

    lua_getglobal( L, "g");
    if (lua_call( L, 0, 0) != 0)
       printf( "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}
```

The Output of print is 0, always. If I put (i+1) in, the Output is always 1. I can't change the value of AUp. The value stays the same, like in the very first call to lua_pushnumner and lua_setglobal.

What is wrong? The function should be called again and again, but the value of AUp can Change, so I have to update it, before calling `lua_call`.

Comment: If you check the immediately pushed number, do you get back that number? eg. `assert( lua_tonumber(L, -1) == i );`? What about checking `AUp` after setting it? eg. `lua_getglobal(L, "AUp"); assert(lua_tonumber(L, -1) == i);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but have You tried:
 1. Defining AUp initial value in Lua script.
 2. Cleaning stack values during C loop. ?

EDIT:
Forget those two points :)

```
for(i = 0; i<200; i++)
   {
            lua_pushnumber(l, i);
            lua_setglobal(l, "foo");

            lua_getglobal(l, "test_f");
            if (lua_pcall(l, 0, 0, 0) != 0)
            {
                    printf( "%s", lua_tostring(l, -1));
            }
    }
```

and

```
function test_f()
    print(foo)
end
```

Works just fine with Lua 5.1.5
Btw, according [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) - `void lua_call (lua_State *L, int nargs, int nresults);` (use `lua_pcall()` instead). Can't even compile Your code with Lua 5.1.5 headers.

Comment: 1. No, because then AUp had to be inside the script
2. How to do this? lua_rawgeti at zhe end of the Loop leads to an exception

Comment: Which Lua version are You using? In my case Your code snippet doesn't compile at all. With lua_pcall() it works well. Also added code snippet.

Comment: I use 4.1. It doesn't have pcall. Good Point. Lua 5 is to big, I use the same Version on the PC and on an ARM9. So I decided to use ver 4.

Comment: @KarlSchulte `lua_settop(L, 0);` will empty the stack.